# Get Post Types in admin

Tags: custom-post-types

I have this code in a page of my custom theme:

```
$args = array(
  'public'   => true,
  '_builtin' => false 
);

$output = 'names'; // names or objects, note names is the default
$operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'

$post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator );
```

This code if loaded in a wp-admin page.

The problem is that I want to load all types of post, I tried changing the built in but it does not work. I want to get the default post of wordpress and the custom post type as woocomerce products. Does someone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom post types can only be registered on the `init` hook. So if you're trying to get the post types before the `init` hook, you will only ever get the built-in ones.

To get custom post types, you need to use a hook after `init`, or later on `init` than the custom post types were registered.

```
function wpse_func() {
  $args = array(
    'public'   => true,
    '_builtin' => false,
  ];
  $post_types = get_post_types( $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_func', PHP_INT_MAX );
//* Or
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'wpse_func' );
```

Comment: Well, but your code will get only public and not builtin types. And OP wants to get all registered types ;)

Comment: Right, this is what I had thought. The problem is that I was loading directly without using the hook wp_loaded then I did not take the custom_post. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need to create variables just to pass them as arguments when calling a function.

And getting back to your problem... You pass 'AND' as last argument, so the conditions will be joined with 'AND' - so you will get only post types that are public AND _builtin.

If you want to get all public OR _builtin post types, then you should use OR operator:

```
$post_types = get_post_types( array('public' => true, '_builtin' => true), 'names', 'or' );
```

But if you want to get all registered post types (not all of them have to be public), then this code will help (you don't wont any conditions in there):

```
$post_types = get_post_types( array(), 'names' );
```